# Defining a subclass with parameters in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

The [documentation on typeclasses in Isabelle](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2017/doc/classes.pdf) (section 3.5) explains how to define additional subclass relations "after the fact", by giving proofs of the missing axioms.  Is there a way to do this when the subclass adds parameters in addition to axioms?

For instance, suppose I have the following classes:

```
class setoid =
fixes eq :: "'a ⇒ 'a ⇒ bool" (infix "≈" 50)
assumes eq_refl : "∀x. x ≈ x"
and eq_symm : "∀x y. x ≈ y ⟶ y ≈ x"
and eq_trans : "∀x y z. x ≈ y ⟶ y ≈ z ⟶ x ≈ z"

class preorder =
fixes le :: "'a ⇒ 'a ⇒ bool" (infix "≲" 50)
assumes le_refl : "∀x. x ≲ x"
and le_trans : "∀x y z. x ≲ y ⟶ y ≲ z ⟶ x ≲ z"
```

Every preorder should be a setoid when we symmetrize its inequality:

```
definition (in preorder) peq :: "'a ⇒ 'a ⇒ bool"
where "peq x y ≡ (x ≲ y) ∧ (y ≲ x)"
```

However, the following fails:

```
subclass (in preorder) setoid
```

with the error `exception TYPE raised: Class preorder lacks parameter(s) "setoid_class.eq" of setoid`.  But I can't figure out a syntax to tell Isabelle that this missing parameter should be the relation `peq` that I defined.

I can do it if I drop down to locales instead of typeclasses (proofs omitted for brevity):

```
interpretation peq_class : setoid peq
proof
show "∀x. peq x x" sorry
show "∀x y. peq x y ⟶ peq y x" sorry
show "∀x y z. peq x y ⟶ peq y z ⟶ peq x z" sorry
qed
```

But this doesn't allow me to use a `preorder` as a `setoid`, i.e. the `interpretation` doesn't act like a `subclass` or an `instantiation`.  What I want is to be able to instantiate a type as a preorder and then automatically be able to use definitions and theorems about setoids on that type, by way of the symmetrization of its inequality.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a restriction of the way type classes are implemented in Isabelle. I'm not sure if the following workaround is as short as it could be, but it works:

```
class eq =
  fixes eq :: "'a ⇒ 'a ⇒ bool" (infix "≈" 50)

class setoid = eq +
  assumes eq_refl : "∀x. x ≈ x"
    and eq_symm : "∀x y. x ≈ y ⟶ y ≈ x"
    and eq_trans : "∀x y z. x ≈ y ⟶ y ≈ z ⟶ x ≈ z"

class preorder =
  fixes le :: "'a ⇒ 'a ⇒ bool" (infix "≲" 50)
  assumes le_refl : "∀x. x ≲ x"
    and le_trans : "∀x y z. x ≲ y ⟶ y ≲ z ⟶ x ≲ z"

class preorder_setoid = preorder + eq +
  assumes eq_def: "x ≈ y ⟷ (x ≲ y) ∧ (y ≲ x)"

subclass (in preorder_setoid) setoid
  apply standard
  unfolding eq_def
  using le_refl le_trans by auto
```

The downside is that you still can't make any instance of `preorder` a `setoid` automatically, but you have to do it manually. For each `preorder` instance, you can add a `preorder_setoid` instance. All of these will look identical; they have to define `eq` according to `eq_def`. The proof is then automatic.

**Update** As pointed out in the comments, the `eq` constant will always be interpreted in the context of the `eq` class; i.e., nothing interesting can be proved without further type annotations. It is possible to tell type inference to do better:

```
setup {*
  Sign.add_const_constraint (@{const_name "eq"}, SOME @{typ "'a::setoid ⇒ 'a ⇒ bool"})
*}
```

Comment: Thanks.  My experience suggests that another downside of this approach is that the symbol `≈` is not attached to the `setoid` class but to the `eq` class, so that Isabelle will not automatically infer that variables to which it is applied must belong to a type that is of class `setoid`.  Is that right?

Comment: That is accurate, but there are tricks. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: After giving that `setup` instruction to type inference, is it possible to annotate a particular use of `eq` to "turn off" the assumption that its argument belongs to a setoid?  In particular, is there a way to define the class `preorder_setoid` *after* the `setup` command has been given?  (For instance, if setoids and preorders are defined in separate theories, it would be natural to give that `setup` command in the setoid file, which is then imported by the preorder theory.)

Comment: You can issue the `setup` declaration right after defining `setoid`. But then, when you define `preorder_setoid`, you first have to remove the additional sort constraints with another `setup` declaration and then add it again.

Comment: Thanks; what would that removal declaration look like?

Comment: Same as the original `setup` declaration, but instead of giving `setoid` as a sort constraint, you give something else (like `eq`).